# Trouble multi-mapping in Dapper .NET Core

Tags: sql, .net, .net-core, dapper

I have the following 2 model classes:

```
public class EnrollableClass
{
    public long EnrollableClassId { get; set; }
    public string ClassEnrollmentCode { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ClassTitle { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ClassGrade { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
    public ICollection<EnrollableClassTeacher> EnrollableClassTeachers { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ClassUnit> ClassUnits { get; set; } = new List<ClassUnit>();
    public ICollection<EnrollableClassStudent> EnrollableClassStudents { get; set; }
}

public class ClassUnit
{
    public long UnitId { get; set; }
    public string UnitTitle { get; set; }
    public string StudentVisibility { get; set; }
    public long EnrollableClassId { get; set; }
    public EnrollableClass EnrollableClass { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to get the `EnrollableClass` back with its units using this but it doesn't map ClassUnit(s):

```
public async Task<EnrollableClass> GetEnrollleableClassWithUnitData(long EnrollableClassId)
{
    var query = @"SELECT EC.[EnrollableClassId], [ClassEnrollmentCode], [ClassTitle], [ClassGrade], [CreatedDate], [LastUpdated],
                    [ClassUnitId], CU.[EnrollableClassId], [UnitCMSDocId], [IsVisible]
                    FROM [spark].[EnrollableClass] EC
                    LEFT JOIN spark.ClassUnit CU ON EC.EnrollableClassId=CU.EnrollableClassId
                    WHERE EC.EnrollableClassId=@EnrollableClassId";

    using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
    {
         var result = await connection.QueryAsync<EnrollableClass, ClassUnit, EnrollableClass>(query,
                (enrollableClass, classUnit) =>
                {
                    enrollableClass.ClassUnits.Add(classUnit);
                    return enrollableClass;
                },
                new { EnrollableClassId = EnrollableClassId },
                splitOn: "EnrollableClassId, ClassUnitId");
            return result.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

For the record this is the result set for the query:

```
EnrollableClassId   ClassEnrollmentCode     ClassTitle  ClassGrade  
CreatedDate     LastUpdated     ClassUnitId     EnrollableClassId   
UnitCMSDocId    IsVisible

1   R8W60G  asdf    5th 2023-10-28 16:32:21.517 2023-10-28 16:32:21.517 2   1   155 1

1   R8W60G  asdf    5th 2023-10-28 16:32:21.517 2023-10-28 16:32:21.517 3   1   156 1
```

Nothing happens when it's run, it throws exception that classUnit is null. I've tried various splitOn params including just `EnrollableClassID` and just `ClassUnitId`, and the combo. This is a one-to-many so I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: And the SO [.net] tag is kind of the opposite of [.net-core]. -- its tooltip explains _"Do NOT use for questions about .NET Core - use [.net-core] instead"_

Comment: There are plenty of examples around the net on how to do this, here [one](https://gist.github.com/grandsilence/e247f9ce8baac2c40adac9856564f2a5). What you need to understand is that you will get a new `enrollableClass` for each line in the result set, so you cannot use it for adding the `classUnit`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code again I realize you actually don't need the dictionary solution I linked in the comment. Here's how you can do it:

```cs
public async Task<EnrollableClass> GetEnrolleableClassWithUnitData(long EnrollableClassId)
{
    var query = @"SELECT EC.[EnrollableClassId], [ClassEnrollmentCode], [ClassTitle], [ClassGrade], [CreatedDate], [LastUpdated],
                    [ClassUnitId], CU.[EnrollableClassId], [UnitCMSDocId], [IsVisible]
                    FROM [spark].[EnrollableClass] EC
                    LEFT JOIN spark.ClassUnit CU ON EC.EnrollableClassId=CU.EnrollableClassId
                    WHERE EC.EnrollableClassId=@EnrollableClassId";

    using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
    {
         EnrollableClass enrollableClass = null;
         var result = await connection.QueryAsync<EnrollableClass, ClassUnit, EnrollableClass>(query,
                (e, classUnit) =>
                {
                    if (enrollableClass = null)
                    {
                        enrollableClass = e;
                    }
                    enrollableClass.ClassUnits.Add(classUnit);
                    return null;
                },
                new { EnrollableClassId = EnrollableClassId },
                splitOn: "ClassUnitId");
        return enrollableClass;
    }
}
```

The trick is to only create one `EnrollableClass` and add the units to that one. The map function can return null, since you aren't using its output and you only need one splitOn to cut the resultset in two.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n7mGEh4_06c&ab_channel=IAmTimCorey). The problem lies in it being a many-to-one which is oddly omitted in the Dapper docs though it's similar to what they do for many-to-many.

Here is my code that works:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<TeacherClassViewModel>> GetAllTeachersClasses(long teacherUserId)
        {
            var query = @"SELECT EC.[EnrollableClassId] As EnrolledClassId, [ClassTitle], [ClassEnrollmentCode], [ClassGrade]
                            FROM spark.EnrollableClassTeacher ECT
                            LEFT JOIN [spark].[EnrollableClass] EC ON EC.EnrollableClassId=ECT.EnrollableClassId
                            WHERE ECT.UserAccountId=@teacherUserId
                            GROUP BY EC.[EnrollableClassId], [ClassTitle], [ClassEnrollmentCode], [ClassGrade]";
            
            var unitQuery = @"SELECT EC.[EnrollableClassId], ClassUnitId
                            FROM spark.EnrollableClassTeacher ECT
                            JOIN [spark].[EnrollableClass] EC ON EC.EnrollableClassId=ECT.EnrollableClassId
                            JOIN spark.ClassUnit CU ON EC.EnrollableClassId=CU.EnrollableClassId
                            WHERE ECT.UserAccountId=@teacherUserId
                            GROUP BY EC.[EnrollableClassId], ClassUnitId";

            using (var connection = _context.CreateConnection())
            {
                var result = await connection.QueryAsync<TeacherClassViewModel>(query, new { teacherUserId = teacherUserId });
                var unitResult = await connection.QueryAsync<ClassUnitRecord>(unitQuery, new { teacherUserId = teacherUserId });

                foreach (var iClass in result)
                {
                    iClass.Units = unitResult.Where(x => x.EnrollableClassId == iClass.EnrolledClassId && x.ClassUnitId != 0).Select(x => x.ClassUnitId).ToList();
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
```